# Yosemite 'About this mac' displaying the wrong storage

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I am having a strange problem where my 'About this mac' > ' Storage' is showing that I Have 470gb of Apps install on a 250gb SSD.

I have used 3rd party disk scanners and they are all showing the correct data. Any idea what this issue is?

[image: Flash storage]

Comment: Could be that one or more of the "Apps" is reporting the wrong size OR the Category it belongs to. What does the Finder says for your App folder size  in the Get Info ?

Comment: I'm also having a 1.88 PB (1,880,000 GB) free diskspace on a 250 GB disk.
Maybe something is wrong. This has happened after the latest update on yosemite.

Comment: Try this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177032/86044